# how to create search function with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have this ajax request that's working on pulling the data I need but I would like to make this a search function that lets the user pull in data as requested. Is there away to take my working code and repurpose it to work with the search box? Not sure how to go about this...

```
function foodQuery(){

    var foodURL = "http://api.example.com/items?key=123456789";

    $.ajax({
        url: foodURL,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "text/plain",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {

            $.each(json.products, function(index, product) { 

                // build product block
                var htmlString = '<div class="product large-3 columns">';
                //open imgwrap
                htmlString += '<div class="imgwrap">';
                //get img src
                htmlString += ' <img class="item_img" src="http://api.example.com/assets/images/' + product.itemCode + '@2x.jpg" />';
                // close imgwrap
                htmlString += '</div>';
                // open textwrap
                htmlString += '<div class="textwrap">';
                // get productName
                htmlString += '<h1 class="product_headline">' + product.productName + '</h1>' ;
                // get itemCode
                htmlString += '<h4 class="item_id" >#' + product.itemCode + '</h4>';
                // get description
                htmlString += '<p class="product_desc">' + product.description + '</p>';
                // open price
                htmlString += '<div class="price">';
                // get price & close div
                htmlString += '<span class="dollar"><span class="usd">$</span>' + product.price + '</span> <span class="product_desc">per weight</span></div>'
                // close divs
                htmlString += '</div>';

                //console.log(htmlString);
                $('.listing').append( $(htmlString) );

           }); //end each

        }, // end success
        error: function(e) {
           console.log(e.message);

           $('.listing').append( '<h1 class="errmsg" >Sorry, there was an unkown error.</h1>' );
        } // end error
    }); // end ajax request
}
```

Comment: why not checking with 'product.productName .IndexOf(smth)' >= 0  in the $.each loop, if true do what u do, unless u tell your server to search, and give u the exact result, you have to search it manually with O(n) cost.

Comment: What will the users type inside the text-box to search the products? is it the `key` in the url?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the API that you are using, but assuming the API has a way to search using text, you could have something that looks like the following:

```
function foodQuery(searchTerm) {
   var foodUrl = '/path/to/api?query=' + searchTerm;

   $.ajax({
     // fill in AJAX call here and callback handling like you are doing
   }) 
}

$('#searchBox').on('keypress', function() {
  foodQuery($(this).val());
});
```

So every time the user types, the function `foodQuery()` will be run with the current search term. You may want to add some delay so that the API is not hit every time the user types a new character.

Answer (score 0):

First create a text input,

```
<input type="text" id="search">
```

Then listen for the `keyup` event of that input. Get the value of the input as the user is typing (if this is the behavior you want) and call the `foodQuery` function sending the value of the input as a parameter. Then use this value as the `key` parameter of the `foodURL`. Then perform the `ajax` request the same way you did.

```
$(function() {

  /** 
  Whenever user types a letter and release the key, its value is passed to the 
  foodQuery function 
  **/
  $("#search").keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    foodQuery(value);
  });

  function foodQuery(key) {    // key is passed as a parameter

    var foodURL = "http://api.example.com/items?key=" + key;

    /** Send you ajax request here and manipulate the DOM the same way yo do. Since we are 
    fetching new products continuously, it is better to clear the .listing element 
    every-time before you update it. **/

    $(".listing").html("");

    /** 
    $.ajax({
        url: foodURL,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "text/plain",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) { **/
  }

});
```

Comment: key has to go at the end of each query so something like this?
 `$("#searchinput").keyup(function() {
 var value = $(this).val();
 foodQuery(value);
 });
 
 function foodQuery(key) {    // key is passed as a parameter
 
 var foodURL = "http://api.example.com/" + value + "?key=" + key;`

Comment: I don't get you. Are you saying that what user will type is used as the `value` in the url? As I see it should just be `items` right?

Comment: I tried your suggested code but I just get the error message every time no matter what I search by